# Insert data to Mysql via minicom hyperterminal

Tags: mysql, linux, raspberry-pi, mysql-connector

I will describe my project and I would like some directions or steps of how can I do it. I am using Raspberry Pi with Raspian(like Debian). I connected a TTL device via USB which gives me some results (say name, surname etc) in my hyperterminal (Cutecom or minicom I have them both). It gives me different results every 10 seconds. I would like to save these results in a mysql database. I installed mysql and I think the next step is to create a table with values (name, surname etc). After that the next step in my opinion is to find a way how to connect it with my hyperterminal to get the next and save them in the database. Is there any code in C++ to do that or maybe some examples with this kind of connections? I am using Codeblocks as IDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hyperterminal is a MSWindows product - not a generic term - while cutecom and minicom are Linux/POSIX terminal emulators. You don't say where the MySQL database is nor what os is on the device where you are running the terminal emulator.

But assuming that the mysql db resides on a seperate machine, running some sort of unix, and the *only* option you have for connecting to the raspberry-pi is via a TTY connection (i.e. you can't run SliP/ppp) then just about any programming language is capable of talking to the raspberry pi unit - you're just writing to and reading from a stream device. The only complication is that you may need to set some ioctls for the baud rate / flow control (if it's Linux, then have a look at the setserial util).

OTOH it may be a lot simpler (and it's certainly a lot more flexible) to use a TCP/IP connection - ppp and slip will implement this over a serial line.

Comment: I will do your steps..Thanks